# How do we deal with duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, answers

So I recently came across an answer that was already previously answered (quite a few months back), and the new answer did not seem to add anything that was not already covered. After a brief discussion in chat, this verdict was as such:

> unless clearly plagiarized, I don't think we do anything with duplicate answers

There is a little bit of disambiguation though, so what is the common/actual practice for this, in terms of flagging, voting, deleting, etc?

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227836/73976) is the answer in question.

Comment: Related: [Am I using the 'very low quality' flag wrongly if the reason is because the answer is an exact duplicate of a previous one?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7038/4797)

Comment: Exact dupe answers/dupes that don't add anything are the bane of my life. Talk about increasing the noise-signal ratio.

Comment: Exact dupe answers/dupes that don't add anything are the bane of my life. Talk about increasing the noise-signal ratio.

Comment: Hurr, hurr, hurr...